# Hiding a type from the UI with Json.Net but exposing one of its property instead

Tags: json.net

Let's say we have business types that we want to expose to the UI in a Restful manner :

```
class ToExpose {
    public ToHide SomeBusinessProperty { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherBusinessProperty { get; set; }
}
```

We then have a type that serves as a wrapper and exposes business types through a `Content` property :

```
class Wrapper
{
    public ToExpose Content { get; set; }
}
```

We would like our UI to be agnostic of type `Wrapper`, so the instances of `Wrapper` need to be serialized by directly exposing its `Content`, and need to be deserialized by reinitializing a `Wrapper` for each properties of that type and populating `Wrapper.Content`.

The standard serialization of a `ToExpose` type could give :

```
{
  "$type": "ToExpose",
  "someBusinessProperty": {
    "$type": "Wrapper",
    "content": {
      "$type": "ToExpose",
      "SomeOtherBusinessProperty": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

We aim for this result :

```
{
  "$type": "ToExpose",
  "SomeBusinessProperty": {
    "$type": "ToExpose",
    "SomeOtherBusinessProperty": "abc"
  }
}
```

We made some digging with `IContractResolver`, `IValueProvider`, `JsonConverter` and `ISerializationBinder` and looked around the Internet for answers but we're not sure what a good design pattern would be.

Comment: Ordinarily I would suggest a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm), but your question is unclear.  In your class `ToExpose` you have a property `public ToHide SomeBusinessProperty` which is getting serialized as a `Wrapper` but you want it serialized as a `ToExpose`.  But how do you convert `ToHide` to `Wrapper`?  Can you share a [mcve] that shows a concrete example of what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. When deserializing we check the $type property. If it's a type that is known to be wrapped, we initialize a `Wrapper` instead of the expected `$type`. Then we initialize the expeted `$type` and assign it to `ToExpose.ToHide`.